# NewLine(\n) alternative in Lua?

Tags: lua

I'm looking for an alternative way to express new line(`\n`) in Lua since my host application doesn't allow users to use `\` character.

Here's my code:

```
local str = "Hello\nWorld"
print(str)
```

Is there any alternative solution to make the same string without using `\n` character?

Comment: You can try `"Hello"..string.char(10)..string.char(13).."World"`

Comment: `string.char(10)` was enough. Thank you!

Comment: @moteus - In what systems `LFCR` is a valid newline?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can enter newlines directly into the string using long strings:

```
local str = [[Hello
World]]
```